# Node can't reach postgres server in docker compose

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm running a NodeJS app and its related services (Redis, Postgres) through docker-compose. My NodeJS app can reach Redis just fine using its name & port from my docker-compose file, but for some reason I can't seem to reach Postgres:

```
  Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN postgres
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26)
```

My docker-compose file:

```yaml
services:
    api:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "3001:3001"
        depends_on:
            - postgres
            - redis

    postgres:
        image: postgres:11.1
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        expose:
            - "5432"
        hostname: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: root
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
            POSTGRES_DB: test
        restart: on-failure
        networks:
            - integration-tests
    redis:
        image: 'docker.io/bitnami/redis:6.0-debian-10'
        environment:
            # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
            - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
            - REDIS_DISABLE_COMMANDS=FLUSHDB,FLUSHALL
        ports:
            - '6379:6379'
        hostname: redis
        volumes:
            - 'redis_data:/bitnami/redis/data'
```

I've tried both normal `lts` and `lts-alpine` base images for my NodeJS app. I'm using `knex`, which delegates connecting to the `pg` library... Anybody have any idea why it won't even connect? I've tried both running directly through `docker-compose` and through `tilt`.

Comment: Remove `networks` section from `postgres` service and restart the services. It should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding :

```
        networks:
            - integration-tests
```

Only for postgres, you create a separate network only for postgres.
By default, docker-compose create a network for all your container inside the same file with the name: `<project-name>_default`. It's why, when using docker-compose all the containers in the same file could communicate using their name.

By specifying a network for postgres, you "ask" to docker-compose to not use the default network for it.

You have 2 solutions:
- Remove the instruction to failback to the default network
- Add the networks instruction to all other containers in your project / or only those who need it

> *Note*: By default, docker-compose will prefixe all your object (container, networks, volume) with the project name. The default project name is the name of the current directory.